# Is there a way to add conversation history when connecting to direct line?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

We are using botframework-webchat v4. Is there any way to provide history that will be shown up in the chat?

This is currently what I have, but its not working, not sure what format should be for activities in store.

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {
        activities: ['{"type":"message",...}'] 
    },
    ({ dispatch }: { dispatch: any }) => (next: any) => (action: any) => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
            const { activity } = action.payload;

            if (activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'sample:backchannel') {
                alert(JSON.stringify(activity, null, 2));
            }
        }

        return next(action);
    }
)

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
        directLine: this.directLine,
        userID: this.userId,
        styleOptions,
        store
    },
    this.botWindowElement.nativeElement
);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by "conversation history"? Are you asking about when a user refreshes a screen or navigates away from the page hosting web chat and then returns? Or, are you referring to a user opening up a bot in web chat that they haven't visited in two weeks and that previous conversation (from two weeks ago) is loaded?

Comment: @StevenKanberg I am trying to show all conversation (no matter it is one day ago or 2 weeks ago). So i guess the only way i can do is to save all conversation, and load them on the client side in angular when connecting to a new conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're solution above will, technically, work. Although, it's not very scalable in the long run. I would recommend you look over this BotFramework-WebChat experimental sample, [Conversation History](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1706). It utilizes the [sendConversationHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-connector/conversations?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#sendconversationhistory-string--transcript--requestoptionsbase-) API. This sample is a bit on the complex side, but will do precisely what you are wanting, i.e. load a previous user's conversation when a new session is started.

If you *are* wanting to reconnect a previous conversation (meaning continue a conversation using the same `conversationId`) then you should be aware that the Direct Line service has certain limitations. Reconnecting will only work for up to 14 days after the last activity to that conversation and only 24 hours if activities are present.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for the input! For sure this is a better solution. Havent had a chance to try this, but I assume this can help us implement infinite scroll - show older conversation when you scroll to the top.

Answer (score 0):

@StevenKanberg Thanks for the help!
I found the answer in source code of BotFramework-WebChat.

Here is the sample,

```
test('absolute timestamp', async () => {
  const activities = [
    {
      type: 'message',
      id: '6266x5ZXhXkBfuIH0fNx0h-o|0000000',
      timestamp: '2019-08-08T16:41:12.9397263Z',
      from: {
        id: 'dl_654b35e09ab4149595a70aa6f1af6f50',
        name: '',
        role: 'user'
      },
      textFormat: 'plain',
      text: 'echo "Hello, World!"'
    },
    {
      type: 'message',
      id: '6266x5ZXhXkBfuIH0fNx0h-o|0000001',
      timestamp: '2019-08-08T16:41:13.1835518Z',
      from: {
        id: 'webchat-mockbot',
        name: 'webchat-mockbot',
        role: 'bot'
      },
      text: 'Echoing back in a separate activity.'
    },
    {
      type: 'message',
      id: '6266x5ZXhXkBfuIH0fNx0h-o|0000002',
      timestamp: '2019-08-08T16:41:13.3963019Z',
      from: {
        id: 'webchat-mockbot',
        name: 'webchat-mockbot',
        role: 'bot'
      },
      text: 'Hello, World!'
    }
  ];
  const styleOptions = { timestampFormat: 'absolute' };
  const { driver } = await setupWebDriver({ storeInitialState: { activities }, props: { styleOptions } });
```